# AWS permissions for Fargate and SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam, fargate

I'm trying to create some infrastructure for a service I am building on AWS using AWS Fargate.  I'm using SSM as a value store for some of my application configuration, so I need both the regular permissions for Fargate as well as additional permissions for SSM.  However, after banging my head against this particular wall for a while, I've come to the conclusion that I just don't understand AWS IAM in general or this problem in particular, so I'm here for help.

The basis of my IAM code comes from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bradford_hamilton/deploying-containers-on-amazons-ecs-using-fargate-and-terraform-part-2-2e6f6a3a957f); the IAM code is actually not in that tutorial but rather in [this file](https://github.com/bradford-hamilton/terraform-ecs-fargate/blob/master/terraform/roles.tf) in the github repo linked to that tutorial.  I presume I need to retain that STS permission for something although I'm not entirely sure what.

I've converted the IAM code from the tutorial into a JSON document because I find JSON easier to work with than the Terraform native thing.  Here's what I've come up with.  It doesn't work.  I would like to know why it doesn't work and how to fix it.  Please ELI5 (explain like I'm 5 years old) because I know nothing about this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What kind of "It doesn't work" do you experience?

Comment: @MLu This particular implementation gives me the error message (from Terraform): "Error: Error creating IAM Role ecs-default-task-execution-role: MalformedPolicyDocument: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions".  I've tried other options that have given me other error messages as well.

Answer (score 1):

IAM Role for Fargate has **two policies**:

1. The first one describes which service can assume the role and its permissions. In this case it will be the `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` service (= Fargate) that can call `sts:AssumeRole` to get all the permissions from this Role.
2. When Fargate *assumes* the role it gets the permissions specified within, these are the SSM, KMS and SecretsManager permissions.

If you are using CloudFormation you can do something like this:

```
  FargateRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        # This says that Fargate can assume this role
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: FargatePermissions
        PolicyDocument:
          # This says what permissions will 
          # the Fargate container receive
          Statement:
          - Action:
            - ssm:GetParameters
            - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
            - kms:Decrypt
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
```

If you are building the role manually in the console be sure to select in the first step that it's an *IAM Role* for *ECS Task*, that will create the equivalent of `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` from the above code snippet.

[image: IAM Role Configuration]

Then in the next step add the policy *without* the `sts:AssumeRole`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

That should create the IAM Role you need. Ideally you should also restrict the access only to specific resources instead of using `"Resource": "*"` but for start it's easier to just use the wildcard.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: As a wrinkle, I'm trying to build this infrastructure using Terraform, which means I can't use the console directly.  I can use the console to create the role once to see what it does, but then I need to translate it to Terraform somehow so I can maintain it.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that my IAM configuration did not include a Task Role, only a Task Execution Role.  I needed to add a Task Role which included the permissions I needed to access SSM, and then it worked.